# Arranging pictures possible combinations

Tags: statistics, permutations, combinations

I'm working on a problem which states there are 26 portraits of men and 4 of women.  It wants to know how many ways can the photos be organized so no women are next to each other.

I assume that the 26 men can be arranged in 26! ways
I am thinking that the second part of the equations is  P(27,4) due to the 27 different spots a woman's picture can be placed.  Is this correct?

I then did 26! * P(27,4) and came out with a huge number that isn't worth adding here but I have assumed that would be the answer.

I more want to check that my logic is correct than anything, I am pretty sure I am at least on track to the right answer if this is not it.

thanks for any help!

Comment: Where have you taken into account that photos of women are not allowed to be placed next to eachother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we only make a distinction between men and women then to be found is the number of ways that $26$ can be written as summation $n_{0}+n_{1}+n_{2}+n_{3}+n_{4}$ where $n_{0},n_{4}$ are nonnegative integers and $n_{1},n_{2},n_{3}$ are positive integers.

(To get a link with 'reality' you could identify each $+$-sign in this expression with a photo of a woman.)

This comes to the same as the number of ways $23$ can be written as summation $m_{0}+m_{1}+m_{2}+m_{3}+m_{4}$ where the $m_{i}$ are nonnegative numbers.

Applying [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))
we find that there are $\binom{27}{4}$ ways.

If also men are distinguishable from eachother and women are distinghuisable from eachother then eventually we find $\binom{27}{4}\times4!\times26!$ ways.

Comment: ah thank you, that makes sense.  I had actually meant C(27,4) in my original question I was not thinking when I put the P(27,4). I would have still gotten 26! * C(27,4) though, i would have been forgetting the 4! so thank you for that

Comment: also, I just did 26! * 4! * C(27,4) and it is the same as 26! * P(27,4), is this a coincidence? Or was I thinking correctly before? Now I am a little confused.

Comment: I think that your original solution $26!P(27,4)$ is a correct one. After placing all men there are $27$ places for the first women. After that $26$ for the second (I realize now that this way women don't get neighbours of eachother) et cetera. At the moment that I made my comment on your question I didn't realize that yet.

Comment: The 'stars and bars' technique used here is a simple way to [partition an integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29), which is generally a very effective way to solve these kinds of problems. And by that I mean 'people sitting in a row, how many ways can one [some condition] occur' type problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : view the 4 women portraits as 4 1's and men portraits as 0's so effectively you need at-least 3 0's between those 1's and the rest 0's can be placed in any of the 5 spots, $\quad$   _1 0 _ 1 0 _ 1 0 _ 1 _ , the '_' denotes the spots